# Button OnClick Listener

Tags: java, android, function, button, onclick

I have a button with the "btnadd" id ,

```
Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
```

And a function with two inputs ,

```
public void CheckNumber (int i , int j) { if (i != j) Toast.makeText(getBaseContext,"i is not equal to j"); }
```

And I want to set this function for the click event of this button

```
add.setOnClickListener(CheckNumber(2,4));
```

This code is not correct, but how can I do this?

Comment: There are a few things which are quite odd here. You always want to pass `2` and `4` as the inputs to `CheckNumber()` function? If yes then why not just hard-code them inside `CheckNumber()` function instead of passing them as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a new View.OnClickListener inside of setOnClickListener. 
Try this:

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             checkNumber(2, 4);
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Complete Solution:**

Try something like this:

First, Create a method: (Consider your case)

```
public void CheckNumber (int i , int j) { 
    if (i != j) 
        Toast.makeText(this, "i is not equal to j", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
}
```

Second, declare the button inside `onCreate()`:

```
Button add = findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
```

Then finally, add a click listener:

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {

         CheckNumber(2, 4);

     }
 });
```

That's it. Hope it helps.